# How to override the built in templates in MVC Core similar in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

in ASP MVC (before MVC core like mvc 4,5 ) , we can override the built in templates like string , boolean from EditorTemplates/Boolean.ascx  ,the question is :
Is there any way to do it in MVC Core similar to this article  https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html  which is applied to MVC 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still works the same way, though it was never `.ascx`. These are Razor views, so they'll need a `.cshtml` extension. Assuming you add a view like `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Boolean.cshtml`, then all you need to do is `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyBooleanProp)`.